# QueryBuilder TypeORM

Tags: sql, postgresql, typescript, typeorm, querybuilder

No meu sistema de gestão patrimonial eu tenho as seguintes tabelas:

**patrimonios:** Os bens patrimoniais.

**patrimonios_cedidos:** A cedência, a lista dos patrimônios cedidos/emprestados.

**patrimonios_cedidos_itens:** Tabela intermediária, que vai registrar o estado de cada patrimônio ao ser emprestado.

Como eu faria para criar uma query utilizando o QueryBuilder da seguinte requisição em PostgreSQL:

```sql
select * from patrimoniodb.patrimonios
where id in (
    select patrimonio_id from patrimoniodb.patrimonios_cedidos_itens
    where patrimonio_cedido_id = 1
)
```

Estou utilizando TypeScript (não sei se tem alguma diferença para o JS), e caso for necessário os campos da tabela ou algo mais, basta me informar que eu edito o post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O nome da propriedade que você precisa usar nessa consulta se chama [`subquery`](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php). É possível criar essa query de duas maneiras (Usando o TypeORM):

```js
const qb = await getRepository(Patrimonios).createQueryBuilder("patrimonios");
const patrimonios = qb
    .where("patrimonios.id IN " + qb.subQuery().select("patrimonios_cedidos_itens.id").from(PatrimoniosCedidosItens, "patrimonios_cedidos_itens").where("patrimonios_cedidos_itens.patrimonio_cedido_id = :patrimonio_cedido_id").getQuery())
    .setParameter("patrimonio_cedido_id", 1)
    .getMany();
```

Ou de uma maneira mais sofisticada:

```js
const patrimonios = await connection.getRepository(Patrimonios)
    .createQueryBuilder("patrimonios")
    .where(qb => {
        const subQuery = qb.subQuery()
            .select("patrimonios_cedidos_itens.id")
            .from(PatrimoniosCedidosItens, "patrimonios_cedidos_itens")
            .where("patrimonios_cedidos_itens.patrimonios_cedido_id = :patrimonio_cedido_id")
            .getQuery();
        return "patrimonios.id IN " + subQuery;
    })
    .setParameter("patrimonio_cedido_id", 1)
    .getMany();
```

Aqui está a referência da resposta (https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/using-subqueries), nesse site você consegue achar outras explicações de como utilizar esse ORM.


Caso queira entender mais sobre essa propriedade `subquery`, basta acessar o link https://imasters.com.br/back-end/como-fazer-subconsultas-um-passo-passo